# Как правильно отправить запрос python

Tags: python, requests

```
class Bot()
    def get_chat_messages(self, chatId: str, size: int, comId: str):

        data = json.dumps({
            "ndcId": f"x{comId}",
            "threadId": chatId,
            "size": size
        })

        response = requests.post("https://somesite.com/api/chat-thread-messages", data=data)
        return response.json()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            messages = self.get_chat_messages(chatId=chatid, size=10, comId=comid)
            print(messages)


bot = Bot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run()
```

Возвращает это:

```
{'code': -1, 'message': 'CSRF check fail'}
```

В чем причина? И как это исправить?

Comment: Прочитайте за CSRF? думаю вопрос отпадет - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: Посмотрите как передаётся заголовок `CSRF`. Обычно это похоже на `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. И добавьте данный заголовок в `headers` запроса.